# how to scroll top automatically to the active menu or sub menu.

Tags: jquery

when we click on menu or submenu it should automatically get the place at the top of the menu. I have tried perfect scrollbar jquery plugin but it is not working.  please provide the best solution.

Comment: see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this-

```
$('#A_ID').click(function (e) {//#A_ID is an example. Use the id of your Anchor
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#DIV_ID').offset().top - 20//#DIV_ID is an example. Use the id of your destination on the page
}, 'slow');
});
```